# Raspbian - ALSA error while using pyaudio

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, alsa, pyaudio

I got error starting like below

```
    Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
    Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.front.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM front
```

While trying to run progrm in python on Raspbian.
PC everything works fine, what should I do in order to resolve my problem?